# Call grails controller from bootstrap?

Tags: grails, bootstrapping

I have a controller action with complex logic to build a model, and I would like to build one during BootStrap.groovy. How can I call that controller action during bootstrap with the required params?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Grails way would be to move the "complex logic" into a service which the controller calls, then call the same service method from bootstrap. You can use autowiring in `BootStrap` the same as in services and controllers, with

```
def myService
```

outside the init closure.